# country-state-region dropdown list in react native

Tags: react-native

I am very new to react-native and was wondering if there was a library in react-native to build a country-state-region dropdown?

I tried to look for it, but have not found accurate answers. Is there a way maybe I can use this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-state-city/v/1.0.2 ?

Comment: Did you found any solutions?